# How to quit pry loop without quiting rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

Sometimes I'm stuck in a long loop when using `binding.pry`.
I can quit the loop by `exit-program`, but the command exit rails console also.

Is there easy way to exit a long loop without quitting `rails console`?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but you may want to try the `disable-pry` command which will automatically iterate though your entire loop without exiting the session.  Another option (albeit not great for long loops) would be to use `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which iterates through a single cycle of a loop.  You would have to enter it repeatedly until your loop was complete, however it would allow you to hit another breakpoint if that's your goal.

For a little more control you may want to add another gem like [byebug](https://rubygems.org/gems/byebug) or [pry-byebug](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry-byebug).

Comment: And then, if you want to re-enable breaking on `binding.pry` after getting out of your loop, use `ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = nil`. There is no `enable-pry` command, but this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug = true
# start loop
    binding.pry if debug
# end loop
```

You can exit each loop iteration individually with `exit`.  Then, when you're ready to step out of debugging and continue the execution of the remaining code, enter `debug = false`.  Then, `exit` will return you to the rails console session.